# Why we should use react slice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, common approach of modifying state of an object is to use temp variable and than overwrite it.
So, the code will look like this:

```
const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
squares[i] = 'X';
this.setState({squares: squares});
```

So, why should we use `slice` function? 
If we're gonna skip that, it will mean that `squares` would be an reference to `this.state.squares` ?

Answer (score 4):

[.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is a javascript function. Use it when you do not want to alter the [original contents](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread), instead a shallow copy of that for local change and usage.